# Apply where condition on the child table in Linq to SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table TableA and child table TableB. I want to fetch all the parent table records,
but select  child records which satisfy a condition. I am using include to get the child records.

Is there any direct way other than using select new?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `select new`?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't filter inner collections. Only option is returning object, which will hold filtered data

Comment: I have many columns in main table and more child tables. If I do select new I have to again write for all the fields and child tables.

Comment: @AvidProgrammer Can you at least show us your models?

Comment: I am sure Simon is referring to code models :)

Comment: @Lazyberezovsky, yes you can. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL has a LoadOptions that you can set on the context to do some powerful things. Most people point to the .LoadWith which eagerly loads child records. There's also an AssociateWith which specifies the filtering to apply on lazy child fetches. Both of them can take a lambda expression for sub child filtering. Here's an example:

```
var lo = new DataLoadOptions();
lo.AssociateWith<Customers>
    (c => c.Orders.Where(o => !o.ShippedDate.HasValue));
this.LoadOptions=lo;

var query = from c in Customers
            select c.Orders;
```

Note, this only works with LINQ to SQL. EF does not support this behavior at this time.

Comment: +1 very interesting, didn't know about this feature (frankly speaking usually I use EF)

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var context = new DbEntities()) {
    foreach (var p in context.Parents) {
        var childQuery = from c in p.Children 
                         where c.whatever == something 
                         select c;
        // Do something with the items in childQuery, like add them to a List<Child>,
        // or maybe a Dictionary<Parent,List<Child>>
    }
}
```